# Angularjs, create customer directive with $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, currently I have an input form for email.

```
<div ng-app="emailApp" ng-controller="emailController">
  <form name="emailSubmitForm">
     <div>
         <input name="emailInput" type="email" ng-model="email" ng-watchchange="checkduplicate(email)" ng-pattern="emailFormat" required />
     </div>
     <div ng-show="isRepeated">Repeated</div>
     <div ng-show="!isRepeated">Not Repeated</div>
     <button ng-disabled="emailSubmitForm.$invalid" ng-click="createRecord()" >Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Originally I use ng-change but it does not fire if it is invalid, therefore I want to change the ng-change function into a directive, but I have no idea how to do it.

I want to change the function below

```
$scope.checkduplicate = function (email) {
    var model= {
        email: email
    };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/IsEmailDuplicated',
        data: model
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isRepeated = !data;
    });
};
```

to something like

```
app.directive('ngWatchchange',function(email){
    // $http.post request
});
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can make use directive controller function to make $http request

Comment: May be I dint get your business rule correctly, but do you really need to worry checking for duplicates if the email address keyed is invalid?

Comment: @Developer Thank you for your comment! Actually what I wanted to fix is when the email change from valid to invalid, it won't trigger the ng-change function thus the message won't change. I end up hiding the message if the email format is invalid to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use $watch if you can't use ng-change (in your controller or in a separated directive, but i wouldn't go that way).
Something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.email }, 
    function (changedEmail) {

       var model= {
           email: email
       };
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: '/Controller/IsEmailDuplicated',
           data: model
       }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.isRepeated = !data;
       });
});
```

This way, you'll send your $http on every email change (but you can personalize it as you want).

If you *still* persist on using a directive, you could try:

```
app.directive('ngWatchchange', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
          ngWatchchange: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attr) {

          $scope.$watch(function () { return scope.ngWatchchange }, 
             function (changedEmail) {

                var model= {
                   email: email
                };
                $http({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: '/Controller/IsEmailDuplicated',
                   data: model
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.isRepeated = !data;
            });
         });
       }           
   };
});
```

Comment: Although the solution works only when the email input is valid, thank you for giving me an alternatives to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create validation directive which checks if email is available, so:

```
<input name="emailInput" type="email" ng-model="email" email-available ng-pattern="emailFormat" required />
<div ng-show="form.emailInput.$error.emailAvailable">Repeated</div>
<div ng-show="!form.emailInput.$error.emailAvailable">Not Repeated</div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('emailAvailable', function ($q, Api) {
  return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$asyncValidators.emailAvailable = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        // if value is empty we leave it to 'required' validator
            if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
              return $q.when();
            }

            return $q(function (resolve, reject) { //we need to return promise
              $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Controller/IsEmailDuplicated',
                data: modelValue
              }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data) {
                     reject(); // e-mail is duplicate so we reject from promise
                   } else {
                     resolve(); // e-mail is not duplicate so we set it as ok
                   }
                 });
            });
          };
        }
      };
```

I've written it from memory so there could be some mistakes but the idea should be fine.